# Kio estas la diferenco inter "la prefera lingvo por elŝutu ludojn en" kaj "la prefera lingvo por elŝuti ludojn en?"

Tags: verbs, word-difference

La demando estas precize pri -u vs -i. Mi scias ke iom da "ke frazoj" havu la -u finado. Kiel estas en mia malantaŭa frazo. Sed mi sentas ke la frazo en mia demando devus havi la -u finado. Ĉu ĉi tio estas vera aŭ malvera? La originala frazo venas el la angla kaj estas "The preferred language for downloading games in."

Comment: Traduki aferojn povas esti bona ekzerco por lerni lingvon. Tamen mi esperas ke vi atendos iomete antaŭ ol kontribui tiun tradukon al la projekto ĉar ŝajnas al mi ke vi ankoraŭ estas en la komenca fazo de via lernado kaj la rezultanta traduko eble ne estos tre bona.

Answer (score 5):

Vd. la difinon de la u-modo ekzemple en [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/verboj/vola.html)

> U-formo montras, ke la ago aŭ stato ne estas reala, sed dezirata, volata, ordonata aŭ celata.

Estas du okazoj, kiam oni uzas la u-modon.

1. por ordoni aŭ peti

Diru al mi vian nomon.

Mi serĉas iun, kiu akompanu min.

2. en ke-frazo, se la ĉeffrazo iel montras volon, celon, opinion k.s.

Mi volas, ke vi laboru.

Li petas, ke mi estu atenta

Via ekzemplo nek estas ordo/peto nek havas tian ke-frazon, do "por elŝuti".

Vi havas memstaran prepozicion "en" ĉe la fino de la frzo. Tio estas malĝuste, ĉar en Esperanto prepozicioj ĉiam devas stari antaŭ sia ĉefvorto. Vi devas reskribi vian frazon. Kiam vi faras tion, notu ankaŭ, ĉu vi volas, ke la uzanto elektas lingvon, en kiu la fasado estas, aŭ lingvon, en kiu la ludoj estas.

Comment: Kio estas la ĝusta traduko? Mi estas preter esti mezlernanto sed ne finiĝis. Mi voluntuliĝas traduki aferoj kiel amuziĝa vojo por plibonigi mian vortprovizon. Sed ĉi tiu frazo estas malfacila al mi.

Comment: Depende de tio pri kiun signifon vi volas: "La preferata lingvo en kiu elŝuti ludojn" (de Neil malsupre) aŭ "La preferata lingvo de ludoj". Tamen ĉi-okaze vi adresas la peton de elekto al uzanto, do mi  preferas aktivon: "Elektu la preferatan lingvon por la fasado" aŭ "Elektu la preferatan lingvon de ludojn".

Answer (score 3):

> “la prefera lingvo por elŝutu ludojn en”

Tiu frazo tute ne apartenas al la lingvo. Neniel oni povas uzi -u formon post `por`.

> “la prefera lingvo por elŝuti ludojn en?”

Ankaŭ tiu frazo ne apartenas al la lingvo. Post `en` vi bezonas ion.

> Kio estas la diferenco inter

Por povi kompari la frazojn kaj trovi malasamon, nuancon, signifon, oni bezonas du ĝustajn frazojn, kaj tion ni ne havas.

Sed vi aldonis la originalan frazon, do ni tamen povas klopodi helpi.

```
The preferred language for downloading games in.
```

Se tuj poste venas la listo de lingvoj (angla, uzbeka, gvarania,...), vi povus ekzemple skribi:

```
Prefere elŝuti ludojn en la:
```

aŭ

```
Preferata lingvo por elŝuto de ludoj.
```

(`elŝuto de`, `elŝutitaj` se oni povas ŝanĝi la lingvon de ludo post la elŝuto, `elŝutotaj` se oni volas klarigi ke la decido aplikeblos ekde nun, ..., ĝenerala kunteksto helpos trovi pli trafan tradukon).

Cetere, notu ke en fasadoj plej ofte oni proponas eblojn en menuoj, same kiel en menuo restoracia, tial oni kutime ne trovas -u formojn krom se temas pri rekta peto/ordono al la uzanto. En la aliaj okazoj vi trovos -(ad)-o/-i formojn.

Answer (score 2):

La formo de la verbo kun *-i* reprezentas plenan frazon. Oni povas uzi ĝin preskaŭ ĉie kie oni uzas substantivon kvazaŭ la frazo estas objekto kiu agas en la ĉefa frazo.

La formo kun *-u* tamen estas modo kaj ĝi devas esti parto de plena frazo. Oni ne povas uzi ĝin kiel parton de frazo kie oni povus meti substantivon. Oni tamen povas meti tutan frazon en tiun rolon se oni metas *ke* antaŭ ĝi.

Ekzemple:

> Mi volas *manĝi*

Tie *manĝi* estas kvazaŭ mallongigo de la plena frazo “mi manĝas”. Oni volas ke tiu ago “mi manĝas” okazu.

Oni ne povas diri “mi volas *manĝu*” ĉar tiel estas du verboj en la frazo. *manĝu* ne povas roli kiel la objekto de la unua verbo.

Aliflanke, oni ja povas uzi plenan frazon en tiu loko se oni komencigas ĝin per *ke*:

> Mi volas ke mi manĝu.

Tio tamen estus stranga vortumo kaj estus pli normale uzi *-i*.

Kiel Juha diris, estas ankaŭ alia eraro en via frazo pri la *en* ĉe la fino. Eble ĝusta traduko povus esti:

> … la prefera lingvo en kiu elŝuti ludojn